# Smart Locks with Alert feature

Tags: security, home-security, smart-lock

Are there any smart lock products that are capable of sending out alerts:

- Alert via text/email when lock is opened with code
- Alerts when lock is forcefully opened
- Alerts when lock becomes unreachable due to Wi-Fi or signals being jammed

Please point me to such a product and recommend.

Answer (score 3):

I think most locks will offer option number 1.

For 2: The Schlage locks state this `Built-in alarm technology senses potential security breaches at the lock, while the low battery indicator offers advanced warning for battery replacement`

Also I found August has the following alerts:

> The Door is locked or unlocked manually
>
> ```
> This alert notifies you when someone operates the August Smart Lock manually by hand or using a key.
> ```
>
> The door is locked or unlocked by a specific user
>
> ```
> This alert notifies you when a specified guest or owner operates the lock via Bluetooth. This includes unlocking the lock using the app
> ```
>
> or Auto-Unlock.
>
> The door is left ajar (3rd Gen Smart Lock and Smart Lock Pro only)
>
> ```
> This alert notifies you if the door is left open for a specific amount of time. Specify the amount of time in the lock settings.
> ```
>
> The door is Auto-Locked
>
> ```
> This alert notifies you when your August Smart Lock Auto-Locks. Auto-Lock can be set up in the lock settings page.
> ```
>
> The door is One-Touch Keypad locked (only if August Smart Keypad
> paired with lock)
>
> ```
> This alert notifies you when the August Smart Lock is locked using the One-Touch Lock feature on the August Smart Keypad.
> ```

For 3: If the door cannot get on Wifi, it cannot contact you.  The only way I could see something like this working is to have a device constantly pinging the door lock.  If it can't find after a certain interval, send an alert.